# How to upgrade my systemd to latest version?

Tags: debian, systemd, upgrade

My OS: Debian 8.

```
sudo systemd --version
systemd 215
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR
sudo aptitude upgrade systemd
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

My systemd can't be upgraded. How can I upgrade my systemd to the latest version?

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade systemd?

Comment: --vacuum-size= and --vacuum-time= were added in systemd v. 218

Comment: "My systemd can't be upgraded" why can't it be upgraded and why do you want to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest way for you to upgrade systemd beyond version 215 (which is the version in Debian 8) is to install the version from [Jessie backports](https://backports.debian.org/). As root:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install systemd
```

This will install (as of this writing) [version 230 of systemd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/systemd).

Comment: if this is too safe, you could try the [package in experimental](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/systemd) (v233 at this writing).  it's slightly less dangerous if you get the source package instead of the binary and compile on your local machine.

Comment: In `systemd`’s case, given the experimental binary package’s dependencies, there’s no need to build the package locally instead of using the binary package available in the repository. The danger in using experimental is that you don’t know *a priori* why the maintainers uploaded the package to experimental... (OK, the reason is easy enough to guess currently, but you still need to check there aren’t any breaking changes in the package.)